# CSS grid make items same height

Tags: html, css, reactjs

At first, [all items in the grid are in the same size i want it  to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOlf4.png)

But after clicking the 'Load More' button, the height for the new items are not the same:
[Example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSGXr.png)

I want to make those items the same height as [shown in the first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOlf4.png), but I'm not sure how

my html

```
<div>
    <Title message={"Your Top Artists"}/>
    <div className="topArtists">
        {toDisplay.map(item=>{
            return(
                <div className="items">
                    <li className="items-li" onClick={(e) => handleClick(e, item)}>
                        <Link to={`${path}/artist/${item.id}`}>
                            {item.name}, {item.followers}, {item.genres}, {item.popularity}
                        </Link>
                    </li>
                </div>
            )
        })}
    </div>
    <button onClick={loadMore}> Load More </button>
</div>
```

And my Css

```
.topArtists{
    /*width: 100%;*/
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 250px);
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    column-gap: 10px;
    row-gap: 15px;

}

.items {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.items-li{
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 25px;
    list-style: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, you have set height for only 3 first rows. Use `grid-auto-rows` instead

```
.topArtists{
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-rows: 250px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    column-gap: 10px;
    row-gap: 15px;
}
```